# Eclipse - How do i add a save/load feature to my .jar game?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am creating a Choose your own adventure in Eclipse Mars 2 and I would like to implement a save feature so i can save the game with a button and re load where i was with another. I am fairly new to programming and don't know how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way of doing this is to save the game state to a file at location *X* on the user's filesystem, and to load the game by reading the file (if any) at location *X*. There are several main challenges here:

1. The user might not appreciate your game writing files. However, file-writing happens all the time by various applications to store settings and other saved information.
2. If the user deletes the file, their save is also lost.
3. You'll have to figure out how to serialize and deserialize your game state to a file.
4. Users now have a way of cheating by modifying the file if they can reverse-engineer your (de)serialization process.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how i can go about coding this process?

Comment: The main thing is to learn how to read and write files. There are plenty of tutorials online covering that.

Comment: I will find one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RobinOfLoxely The most appropriate way to thank on StackOverflow is to mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: Thank you, i will. I am new here.